# Sharepoint Authentication Windows and Custom Login Form

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, windows-authentication

We're trying to find a way to implement a rater tricky scenario.

We want to create a web app with Claims Based Windows Authentication, so that in a machine in the local domain the authentication is transparent.

This is simple.

Now, for users accessing the web app from outside the company we want to have a custom login page. Partially because we don't like the look and feel of the default login window, and partially because of the need to insert the domain on windows/ie machines.

Is there a way to do this, without enabling forms auth (this breaks the seamless auth in local machines)

We currently are looking at:

- a custom http module
- editing _windows/default.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Am facing the same problem as u were. Can you please let me know the proper way that resolved custom login page without using FBA? Thanks in advance
AK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually done by creating a custom Signin page which directs you to the right login page based on ip-range instead of having the user select the authentication provider in a dropdown.

You can find one solution at [SharePoint 2010 automatic sign-in with mixed authentication](http://spautomaticsignin.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. We actually already found that page, but there is still a situation that is not functional. If we take a domain laptop home since it's on an outside IP it will show the login form.

Comment: My only suggestion is to combine the above with adding a link for the laptop user to login automatically as Liam does in [SharePoint 2010 and Custom ADFS Login](http://blog.helloitsliam.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=76)

Comment: Again thank you for your reply. But this solution does not work for us either. ADFS 2.0 requires that the domain controllers are 2008 machines, and in our scenario they are 2003.

Comment: Still I'll mark you reply as answer because for most situations these are two very good solutions

Comment: You don't need ADFS it was more the idea of adding a link to the Forms login page to let laptop users outside the company ip-ranges click the link to automatically log in.

Comment: Ok, but that approach breaks the automatic login for applications (search, outlook syncronization of list, etc...)